# Need help with handling weighted sum "score" value to always be between 0-10

Tags: logic

I'm working on a formula to represent a score for a unique asset where the input is based on the output from multiple tool sources. I'll try to break down what I have so far.

(value1 * 0.50) + (value2 * .025) + (value3 * 0.15) + (value4 * 0.10) = tool1 weighted sum

Each tool also has it's own weight and the same formula so far has been used to obtain it. The weighted sum of each tool is then used to obtain the final weighted score.

(tool1 * 0.30) + (tool2 * 0.25) + (tool3 * 0.20) + (tool3 * 0.15) + (tool3 * 0.10) = asset weighted score

From here I'm trying to change the asset weighted score to be represented within 0-10 range. I have found that I can divide the asset weighted score by the total count of "value" items used to obtain the tool weighted sum across all tools, and then multiple that by 100 and get in the desired 1-10 range, but this only works if there are at least 5 of the input value contain higher than 0. When this isn't met then the asset weighted score falls outside the 0-10 range.

The input values can range from 0 to an unknown amount. It will always be a positive number but the cap is unknown because it is a sum of all values that match that check. I don't really expect them to go any higher than 10, 000 at the highest and even that seems like an edge case. Ideally, most inputs will be lower, below 100, if not below 20 for each input value.

To summarize, the issue I'm facing is that if there are too few input values, then the asset weighted score doesn't fall within the desired 0-10 range with my current formula, but I'm not really sure what to research in order to help fix this issue. I don't really have a lot of history with big math problems, but willing to learn in order to help build the right formula.

--- Edit #1 to hopefully provide more details of what I have so far and where I'm stuck

Table of input data for each tool and each types weight. There will 5 tools total that each have 4 type values each. The type value names/sorting criteria are the same across each tool output.

| tools | types | count | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tool1 | type1 | 1 | 0.5 |
| tool1 | type2 | 7 | 0.25 |
| tool1 | type3 | 3 | 0.15 |
| tool1 | type4 | 2 | 0.1 |
| tool2 | type1 | 89 | 0.6 |
| tool2 | type2 | 12 | 0.25 |
| tool2 | type3 | 7 | 0.15 |
| tool2 | type4 | 5 | 0.1 |

To use tool 1 as an example, the type weight formula per tool right now is:
(type1 count * weight) + (type2 count * weight) + (type3 count * weight) + (type3 count * weight) / (type1 count + type2 count + type3 count + type4 count)
(1*0.6)+(7*0.25)+(3*0.15)+(2*0.1) / (1+7+3+2)

| tools | type weight avg per tool | tool weight | tool weighted value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tool1 | 2.815384615 | 0.7 | 1.970769231 |
| tool2 | 57.45442478 | 0.3 | 17.23632743 |

Once I have the "tool weighted value" I'm sort of stuck. I'd like to have the final output be represented from 0-10 to give an overall "score" based on all the inputs. I can of course multiply the "tool weighted value" by some value I choose to get in a 0-10 range, but the output won't stay within that range if the counts are too low, such as a single type having a count of 2 and all others across all tools are 0. The ideal desired state for the output is for all counts across all types and all tools to be at or as close to 0 as possible.

I had a friend suggest some form of normalization, "maybe a sigmoid and multiplying by 10", but I'm not familiar with that so researching it now.

I hope this helps out. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: This is not clear yet. Do you really want tool1 four out of five times in the second equation? f you [edit] the question to show us a table of some sample values and the computations you make, including some that succeed and some that don't, we might be able to help.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for responding! I made some edits and hopefully provided more useful information. I haven't done anything near this level of math in probably over a year back in earlier college days, so trying to research and catch up. Happy to do the leg work but not sure which direction I should really focus on in my research.